# View or open PDF files stored locally Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a solution to view or open PDF Files using Expo (without Expo eject)?
It's not necessary to open file inside App, it's can be a local filemanager.

What i tried:

- [Linking](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/) does not open locally files, only online sources
- [React Native PDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf) doesn't work with expo
- [Expo Media Library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/media-library/) allows to download files, but not open it.

Answer (score 16):

**My solution:**

Use [FileSystem.getContentUriAsync()](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemgetcontenturiasyncfileuri)  and [Expo IntentLauncher](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/)

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher';

FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri).then(cUri => {
  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
      data: cUri.uri,
      flags: 1,
      type: 'application/pdf'
   });
});
```

[image]

Comment: For me this produces the following error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method startActivity on module ExpoIntentLauncher: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/pdf flg=0x1 }]` -- any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: not working .  Getting No Activity found to handle Intent

Comment: is it working on iOS?

Answer (score 6):

I tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813652/16799160 and I get this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method startActivity on module ExpoIntentLauncher: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/pdf flg=0x1 }]

After that, I modified data: cUri.uri to data: cUri based on [expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemgetcontenturiasyncfileuri) and works fine. 
***Remember, this is an android-only solution***

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher';

try {

  const cUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri);
             
  await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
      data: cUri,
      flags: 1,
      type: "application/pdf",
  });
}catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For android the IntentLauncher approach will work great.
For ios, it is recommended to have another approach:

Install the expo dependencies:

```
npx expo install expo-sharing
```

The the code may be like that:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';

FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri).then(cUri => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        Sharing.shareAsync(cUri.uri);
    } else {
        IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
            data: cUri.uri,
            flags: 1,
            type: 'application/pdf',
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher';
  
 const uri = FileSystem.documentDirectory  + 'Example'.xlsx;

 FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri).then(cUri => {
                console.log(cUri);
                IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
                  data: cUri,
                  flags: 1,
                });
              });
```

Note: get your filelocation on uri