# Cannot read property open of null in react-native-file-viewer

Tags: react-native, expo

I just installed react-native-file-viewer in my react native app and tested its open method to read the document that I generated using the app. However, I always encounter an error message saying "Cannot read property open of null"

I checked the URI that generated from StorageAccessFramework and there seem no issue and the file is successfully created using expo-file-system.

the only problem is with opening the file using react-native-file-viewer.

is there something I need to make that error gone?

I followed the instruction on installing the fileviewer in react native with expo..

EDIT:

This is my code in react native

common.helper.ts

```
import * as Print from 'expo-print'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { StorageAccessFramework } from 'expo-file-system';
import RNFileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';

export const exportBarcodeAndSaveAsPdf = async (barcodes: string[] = []) => {

    const html = createHtml()
    .build(
        createHtml()
        .createTable(
            barcodes.map(o => 
                createHtml()
                .createImage(o, ['style="width: 115px; height: 115px;"'])
            ),
            5
        )
    );

    try 
    {
        const {base64} = await Print.printToFileAsync({
            html,
            base64: true
        });

        switch(Platform.OS)
        {
            case 'android':
                {
                    
                    const permission = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();

                    if(!permission.granted)
                    {
                        return;
                    }


                    const dateText = dateTimeText();
                    const fileName = `My-Barcode-${dateText}.pdf`;
                    const uri = await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permission.directoryUri, fileName , 'application/pdf');

                    console.log(uri);
                    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, base64, {encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64});

                    await RNFileViewer.open(uri, {showOpenWithDialog: true, showAppsSuggestions: true});
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.log(ex);
    }

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myfirst-mobile",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@kichiyaki/react-native-barcode-generator": "^0.6.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
    "expo": "~50.0.7",
    "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
    "expo-camera": "14.0.5",
    "expo-file-system": "~16.0.5",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.9.1",
    "expo-print": "~12.8.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~13.2.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "^2.9.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.3",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "realm": "^12.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'MyFirst Mobile'

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  versionCatalogs {
    reactAndroidLibs {
      from(files(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../gradle/libs.versions.toml")))
    }
  }
}

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native/gradle-plugin/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())

include ':react-native-file-viewer'
project(':react-native-file-viewer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-file-viewer/android')
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RUNTIME_VERSION" android:value="@string/expo_runtime_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.ajp.ajpmobile"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <provider android:name="com.vinzscam.reactnativefileviewer.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_viewer_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true";

    if (isGifEnabled) {
        // For animated gif support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:${reactAndroidLibs.versions.fresco.get()}")
    }

    if (isWebpEnabled) {
        // For webp support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:${reactAndroidLibs.versions.fresco.get()}")
        if (isWebpAnimatedEnabled) {
            // Animated webp support
            implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:${reactAndroidLibs.versions.fresco.get()}")
        }
    }

    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation project(':react-native-file-viewer')
}
...
```

MainApplication.kt

```
package com.myfirst.myfirstmobile

import android.app.Application
import android.content.res.Configuration
import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactHost.getDefaultReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper

import com.vinzscam.reactnativefileviewer.RNFileViewerPackage;

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost = ReactNativeHostWrapper(
        this,
        object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
          override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> = PackageList(this).packages.apply {
            // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
            // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            add(RNFileViewerPackage())
          }

          override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = ".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"

          override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

          override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
          override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
      }
  )

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = getDefaultReactHost(this.applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    if (!BuildConfig.REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS) {
      ReactFeatureFlags.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways = false
    }
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager)
    }
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this)
  }

  override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig)
  }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Please share some code snippet demonstrating the issue so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I shared the my code in my app together with the react-native-file-viewer changes in native code.

Comment: looks like this is a issue with the package itself..I'll inform the owner about this. the cause of this error is with the nativemodules not getting converted into javascript code

Comment: My bad. the issue is still existent regardless of it. everything are set just fine. I am really confuses what else to check on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out why its not working.

its because I am running the application with the expo commands

expo is not taking manual changes in native codes so I drop the idea of using react-native-file-viewer
and luckily I found expo-intent-launcher which is the best solution for me as it is an expo package

here is the SO reference I got with usage:

[View or open PDF files stored locally Expo React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812941/view-or-open-pdf-files-stored-locally-expo-react-native)